# CSS Border Not Working

Tags: css, border

I've been trying to get a border on either side of [my white container](http://glamourunderground.com). It's just not showing. I've tried to put it in three different elements just in case! (see below). Any ideas on how to make it work?

```
#wrapper {
    width:1000px;
    background:#F4F4F4;
    padding-top:5px;
    border: 3px #CDCDCD;
    overflow: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;  
}

#casing {
    padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background:#Fff;
    border: 0 1px 0 1px solid #000;
}   

#cover {
    border: 0 1px 0 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Do this:

```
border: solid #000;
border-width: 0 1px;
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/aFzKy/

Comment: That's cool. But this doesn't work... Now I'm confused! ;)

>#box {
    width:100px; height:100px;
    border:solid red;
    border-width:0 5px 0 5px;
}

Comment: @Tara I don't understand. Doesn't the demo show that it works?

Comment: This code 'border-width:0 5px 0 5px;' is no different to this code 'border-width:0 5px;' but I expected that it would be...

Comment: @Tara `border-width:0 1px` is a shorthand for `border-width:0 1px 0 1px` - they are equivalent. However, inside the `border` property, you cannot define multiple length values - `border:0 1px solid #000` is invalid. That's why (in my solution) I first use `border` to define the border style and color, and then I use `border-width` to define the various border-lengths. Compared to the currently accepted solution, my solution is better because it is not redundant. [Read here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @sime. Your method is more streamline so I'll accept it as best answer.

Comment: include border-left-style:hidden;

Answer (score 19):

I think you've just made up shorthand syntax for the `border:` property there =)

Try simply:

```
border-right: 1px solid #000;
border-left: 1px solid #000;
```

Comment: I'm surprised that the OP's syntax doesn't work - it looks like it ought to, given the way CSS properties generally work, but it doesn't. The answer given is a good alternative, so +1.

Comment: @Spudley Indeed, it's reminiscent of the box-shadow syntax.

Comment: Lol :) I had no idea, I just assumed it would work the same way as padding and margins.

Comment: @Spudly Yeah same, box shadow is just this (has an extra colour parameter!): `0px 0px 5px 5px #000000`

Comment: Thanks, the problem for me was I needed to set border-style to solid.

Answer (score 11):

Use this line of code in your css

```
border: 1px solid #000 !important;
```

or if you want border only in left and right side of container then use:

```
border-right: 1px solid #000 !important;
border-left: 1px solid #000 !important;
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using Firebug to inspect the rendered HTML, and to see exactly what css is being applied to the various elements?  That should pick up css errors like the ones mentioned above, and you can see what styles are being inherited and from where - it is an invaluable too in any css debugging.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, there's no such shorthand for border. You have to define each border separately:

```
border: 0 solid #000;
border-left: 1px solid #000;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
```

Answer (score 3):

The height is a 100% unsure, try putting `display: block; or display: inline-block;`

Answer (score 3):

You forget to add Border style, Do this

```
border-style: solid
```

Or you can write

```
border: 3px #CDCDCD solid
```

Answer (score 0):

In latest version, i just experienced to get a border you have to first set the border-style. Then, the rest border width or color is considered.

```css
border-style: solid;
border-width: 2px;
border:blueviolet;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if somewhere in a code you are not using this style:

```
border-top: none;
```

Or any other variation of border-{side}: none.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot shorthand concept in the border.
Simply use :-
borderWidth: '1px',
border: 'solid #BDBDBD'   // This is color which u can as per ur need.

Answer (score 0):

## Maybe you can use Position: "Relative" to fix it

All the other answers can be helpful, but what worked for me it was using the **position relative** because some child element was overlapping my border.

```
position: 'relative',
border: '2px solid #000'
```